# Using android geocoding in a regular java project

Tags: java, android, geocoding

I have done some Google research off and on for a week or so on the subject, And I have not found anything conclusive. I am just wondering if it is possible to use the geocoding found in android on a regular java project?

I have been looking and all the geocoding i have seen for regular java seems to have some restrictions on its use, and I do not remember reading anything of the sort with the android geocoder so I am trying to use this instead of others. However if anyone does have some good suggests for a geocoder for a java program please let me know.

thanks,
bob

P.S I would rather not use the google api because it only wants it to be displayed on a map which I am not doing. I am trying to store them in a database. And the other google option has a daily limit on the amount of calls to there api so again as mentioned this is a restriction.

as mentioned on the google api page it states "Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions."

So this is not a option for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use Google's geocoding API based on HTTP requests.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: yes but the issue is that it has restrictions as I mentioned above. I would prefer to not have any limits on its use which I am pretty sure the android one does not.